# Computed Tomography: Matlab to C/OpenCV code conversion error

Tags: c, matlab, tomography-reconstruction

I am working on a Computed Tomography problem, in which I have to simulate the generation of the raw data or sinogram that a CT apparatus generates.

Matlab has an in-built function "radon()" to simulate the same. I have successfully written a custom code in Matlab to generate the sinogram (ie: without using radon() ).

I have converted this code into C, using the OpenCV library to handle the loading/display/saving of images.

The problem is that though my matlab output generates the sinogram as expected, my C code does not. I have merely translated the Matlab code into C but the C output is oriented differently as well has black strips in between. The gray levels in the C output kind of resemble the Sinogram gray levels and pattern generated by the matlab code. Only thing it appears segmented in C.(I will send the images across if you gimme your mail id since i cannot attach them here.)

Could someone help me out as to why this is happening? I have peer-reviewed my code and checked for type cast errors, memory allocations etc. But They all seem correct.

Does matlab handle data that differently than C? What could be the explanation for the tilt?

Please Help me out. Do let me know if you need any more clarification regarding the problem statement or need to see the algorithm.

Thanks!

Comment: 'I have peer-reviewed my code' --- surely you mean to write 'one of my peers has reviewed my code'.  If not, then get one of your peers to review your code.

Comment: wild guess: integer divsion instead of float division at some point in you algorithm? anyway...  verifying the output of the C sinogram vs Matlab sinogram shoudln't be too hard.. just printf some junk and check...

Answer (score 0):

Very hard to help with a question like this, when we don't see either code, the output, or the expected output.

Perhaps you can upload the images to some public image hosting, and add links from the question?

If you're doing trigonometric function calls (`sin()` and friends), I would pay extra attention to the arguments used, and also check if maybe Matlab is delivering more precision in the result, somehow. Of course, this is a stab in the dark since I'm not familiar with your domain.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the images related to the doubt I asked in the original post

The expected output:
http://www.photoshop.com/users/pyridot/albums/a40e3f7326d942ff821fc00612e6b458/view#e027c2b94bfd4210870bc6c57b1f1a03

The C Output:
http://www.photoshop.com/users/pyridot/albums/a40e3f7326d942ff821fc00612e6b458/view#ff529abedb3e49aa8865276f2c2bc625

Comment: Also this is the document containing the matlab code which i am trying to convert into C 
http://www.cvmt.dk/education/teaching/e07/MED3/IP/Carsten_Hoilund_-_Radon_Transform.pdf